# How to create a loadbalancer backend service with HTTPS protocol by default in kubernetes ingress on GCP

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

What I am trying to do, is to deploy an API on Kubernetes and, using Google-managed SSL certificates, redirect it to point on my domain on HTTPS protocol.

I have already spent some time on it and done a lot of debugging, but there is one thing that I can't succeed to fix.

What is already done and works:

- Static IP is reserved
- Google-managed SSL certificate is Active and verified
- Both Ingress and Service NodePort are deployed using **443 HTTPS protocol**.
- Health Checks I managed to put on HTTPS as well.

Problem:

- I cannot change the default configuration for loadbalancer backend service. It is always on HTTP.

[Problematic place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFFXy.png)

**BUT** if I change it manually to HTTPS, **API works as expected on my domain** *api.mydomain.com*. The problem is that in 5 minutes, the default configurations are sync with the current configuration in K8s, and the protocol changes to HTTP automatically.

My question: how can set a default configuration to HTTPS for backend service which will not be overwritten afterward.

Here is the guide that I partially followed:

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs#console

And my configurations for Ingress, Service and Health Check

**healthcheck.yaml**

```
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: api-default-config
spec:
  healthCheck:
    checkIntervalSec: 60
    timeoutSec: 60
    healthyThreshold: 1
    unhealthyThreshold: 10
    type: HTTPS
    requestPath: /
    port: 31303
```

**service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: management-api-test-service
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"default": "api-default-config"}'
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: management-api-test
    environment: test
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 443
    targetPort: 5000
    nodePort: 31303
```

**ingress.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: api-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: api-test2
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: test-cert
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: management-api-test-service
      port:
        number: 443
  rules:
  - host: api.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: management-api-test-service
            port:
              number: 443
```

**kubectl describe svc management-api-test-service -n web-application**

```
Name:                     management-api-test-service
Namespace:                web-application
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              cloud.google.com/backend-config: {"default": "api-default-config"}
Selector:                 app=management-api-test,environment=test
Type:                     NodePort
IP Families:              <none>
IP:                       **.***.**.130
IPs:                      <none>
Port:                     <unset>  443/TCP
TargetPort:               5000/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31303/TCP
Endpoints:                **.***.*.13:5000
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

**kubectl describe ingress api-ingress  -n web-application**

```
Name:             api-ingress
Namespace:        web-application
Address:          **.***.***.196
Default backend:  management-api-test-service:443 (***.**.**.13:5000)
Rules:
  Host                    Path  Backends
  ----                    ----  --------
  api.mydomain.com
                          /*   management-api-test-service:443 (***.**.**.13:5000)
Annotations:              ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert: mcrt-blablabla
                          ingress.kubernetes.io/backends: {"k8s-be-31303--efb221b572e568cb":"HEALTHY"}
                          ingress.kubernetes.io/https-forwarding-rule: k8s2-fs-1xka7p8q-web-application-api-ingress-5jc6y1ty
                          ingress.kubernetes.io/https-target-proxy: k8s2-ts-1xka7p8q-web-application-api-ingress-5jc6y1ty
                          ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-cert: mcrt-blablabla
                          ingress.kubernetes.io/url-map: k8s2-um-1xka7p8q-web-application-api-ingress-5jc6y1ty
                          kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: false
                          kubernetes.io/ingress.class: gce
                          kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: api-test2
                          networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: test-cert
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age                   From                     Message
  ----    ------  ----                  ----                     -------
  Normal  Sync    5m2s (x22 over 155m)  loadbalancer-controller  Scheduled for sync
```

**I TRIED**:

- `kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: false` changes nothing
- some configuration with nginx, where http set to "false", but I cannot find it and it did not work.

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 4):

Found it!!!

In the **service.yaml** in the annotations had to add another config and attribute a name to my port. Here is a new config

**service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: management-api-test-service
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"default": "api-default-config"}'
    cloud.google.com/app-protocols: '{"my-https-port":"HTTPS"}' # new line
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: management-api-test
    environment: test
  ports:
  - name: my-https-port # add port name
    protocol: TCP
    port: 443
    targetPort: 5000
    nodePort: 31303
```